# How to remove 3 dots at end of Yaml file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, file-processing, yamldotnet

I'm using YamlDotNet Nuget-package to read and write a Yaml file in C#/.Net Framework. While writing yaml file, it creates 3 dots at end of file. Since these dots are optional so I don't want them. Is there a way to exclude them while creating yaml file?
This is my code.

```
   using YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel;

        var input = new StreamReader(Constants.YamlFilePath);
        var yaml = new YamlStream(); 
        yaml.Load(input);
        input.Dispose();
        var config = ((YamlMappingNode)yaml.Documents[0].RootNode).Children["Configuration"];
        ((YamlMappingNode)yaml.Documents[0].RootNode).Children["Configuration"] = new YamlMappingNode
        {
            { "A1", data.A1 },
            { "A2", data.A2 },
            { "A3", data.A3 },
            { "A4", config["A4"].ToString() },
            { "A5", config["A5"].ToString() }
        };

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Constants.YamlFilePath, false))
            yaml.Save(writer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently `YamlStream` always emits an explicit `DocumentEnd` event, which is why the dots are written. You can't change that behaviour, but you can write your own `IEmitter` to force the `DocumentEnd` event to be implicit:

```
public class NoDotsEmitter : IEmitter
{
    private readonly IEmitter inner;

    public NoDotsEmitter(IEmitter inner)
    {
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public void Emit(ParsingEvent @event)
    {
        if (@event is DocumentEnd documentEnd)
        {
            inner.Emit(new DocumentEnd(true));
        }
        else
        {
            inner.Emit(@event);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then pass an instance of this class to the Save method:

```
var emitter = new NoDotsEmitter(new Emitter(writer));
yaml.Save(emitter, false);
```

You can see a working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2yCM2K

Answer (score 0):

You could create a memory stream, do your write, then write the bytes in the memory stream to the file.

Alternatively, you could create a stream writer that writes all the bytes except the last 3 at each call to write.